# Phabricator: The requested URL returned error: 500 with git Push

Tags: git, phabricator

I had set up [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org) with Diffusion today and have been fighting a

> The requested URL returned error: 500

while trying to git push over http/s (also with clone requests).

I know the remote is correct and I have the VCS password set and `diffusion.allow-http-auth` is set to true.  I am also not getting any (setup) errors in the control panel.

**The Sudoer file is set as follows:**

```
# User privilege specification
root         ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
daemon-user  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
www-user     ALL=(daemon-user) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
git          ALL=(daemon-user) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/git-core/git-upload-pack, /usr/lib/git-core/git-receive-pack
```

**The `clone` and `remote` is:**

```
http://[SUB.DOMAIN]/diffusion/[CALLSIGN]/[REPO].git
```

I do not know how to set up SSH (yet) on ComputeEngine because GCE uses port 22 for the online terminal... :P  So for now I am stuck using git over HTTP.

If anyone out there has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We use ssh. When we started using Phabricator, a lot of developers found it hard to get used to the long-winded syntax for a git clone `git clone git@phab.example.com:diffusion/CALLSIGN`  This is the same URL that needs to be setup for the remote in git.  If this is wrong, that could explain your errors.  When you clone, do you use `git clone https://git@phab.example.com:diffusion/CALLSIGN` or some other command?

Comment: @CEPA Plz see edit in [my Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28844269/742030).  Thnx.

Comment: :( I'm not sure what is missing then.  I recommend getting on phabricator's IRC channel on freenode.net  I wish you could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a line `Defaults requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers`? If it's there, it must be commented out, otherwise phabricator is not allowed to run the commands without a terminal (and of course it has no terminal ...).